# lua table.sort crashes with "attempt to compare nil with string"

Tags: lua, embedded-linux, yocto

I am trying to use lua on an embedded linux device. `table.sort` gives a wired error `attempt to compare nil with string`. I tied exactly this code on my local lua interpreter and it worked. What could cause such a behavior? The embedded lua is compiled through `yocto`.

```
# lua
Lua 5.3.5  Copyright (C) 1994-2018 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> a={}
> a[#a+1]="foo"
> a[#a+1]="baar"
> a[#a+1]="baar_1"
> a[#a+1]="baar_2"
> print(a[0])
nil
> print(#a)  
4
> for i=0,#a do print (a[i]) 
>> end
nil
foo
baar
baar_1
baar_2
> table.sort(a)
attempt to compare nil with string
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'table.sort'
        stdin:1: in main chunk
        [C]: in ?
> table.sort(a, function(x,y) print(x); print(y); return x < y end)
foo
baar_2
nil
baar_2
stdin:1: attempt to compare nil with string
stack traceback:
        stdin:1: in function <stdin:1>
        [C]: in function 'table.sort'
        stdin:1: in main chunk
        [C]: in ?
>  for key, val in pairs(a) do print(key, val) end
1       foo
2       baar
3       baar_1
4       baar_2
>
```

- (update #1 added print)
- (update #2 added print to table.sort)
- (update #3 added loop over key/val)

Comment: Type `print(a[0])` and `print(#a)` in your console; then `for i=0,#a do print (a[i]) end`. You might see nils or unexpected indices like zero.

Comment: @AlexanderMashin you are right, `a[0]` is `nil` and when i loop over the table it begins at 0 not at 1

Comment: `a[0]` should be `nil`, since Lua arrays begin from one. The question is, whether `table.sort` tries to compare a non-existing value, like `a[0]`.

Comment: Here's another idea: `table.sort(a, function(x,y) print(x); print(y); return x < y end)`. Again, there's a chance to see unexpected nils.

Comment: Som there's definitely a `nil` in `a`. Try `for key, val in pairs(a) do print(key, val) end`; perhaps, you'll see where the `nil` is.

Comment: no luck, this is really confusing.

Comment: Well, I think there's a workaround (although this is no solution): `table.sort(a, function(x,y) return x == nil and y ~= nil or x ~= nil and y ~= nil and x < y end)`.

Comment: Alternatively,  you could try `collectgarbage()` before `table.sort`.

Comment: Where did you get the source you compiled? it seems there were some issues for yocto with 5.3 initially (it seems some libraries and function were not working properly), but this was some time ago.

Comment: i use the version from [yocto meta-openembeded](https://github.com/openembedded/meta-openembedded/blob/7c37f90893723f8c9432825c00e4ecbfab292ef5/meta-oe/recipes-devtools/lua/lua_5.3.5.bb) => [http://www.lua.org/ftp/lua-5.3.5.tar.gz](http://www.lua.org/ftp/lua-5.3.5.tar.gz)